# Can I programmatically create a DSA key if I have the parameters?

Tags: ruby, cryptography

There is a private DSA key where I have parameters 'p', 'q', 'g' and 'x' which are hard-coded in another component of our system written in another language.

I would like to try and replicate this logic in Ruby.

I notice that if I create a *new* key:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'openssl'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> key = OpenSSL::PKey::DSA.generate(1024)
=> #<OpenSSL::PKey::DSA:0x007fc756006020>
irb(main):003:0> key.params
=> {"p"=>#<OpenSSL::BN:0x007fc75404e250>, "q"=>#<OpenSSL::BN:0x007fc75404e1d8>, "g"=>#<OpenSSL::BN:0x007fc75404e160>, "pub_key"=>#<OpenSSL::BN:0x007fc75404e0e8>, "priv_key"=>#<OpenSSL::BN:0x007fc75404e070>}
```

This seems to hint to the parameters being the same things we have in the other code...

So is there some way, given that I know the values I want these set to, to create an instance of `OpenSSL::PKey::DSA` with these parameters?

Comment: Seems to me that you should rather read a key file you have on disk than generate the same one again.

Comment: Mmm... though I don't have a key file, I have the parameters. I would have to jump through just as many hoops to get the other code to spit a file out, and then I'd end up with two pieces of code that get the same key using two different methods.